# Is it a code smell if an object knows a lot of its owner?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns

In our Delphi 2007 application we are using a lot of the following constructs

```
FdmBasic:=TdmBasicData(FindOwnerClass(AOwner,TdmBasicData));
```

The FindOwnerClass travels the Owner hierarchy of the current component upwards to find a specific class (in the example TdmBasicData). The resulting object is stored in the Field variable FdmBasic. We use this primarily to pass datamodules along.

Example:
When generating a report, the resulting data is compressed and stored in a Blob field of a table accessed through a datamodule TdmReportBaseData. In a separate module of our application, there is functionality to show the data from the report in a Paged form using ReportBuilder. The main code of this module (TdmRBReport), uses a class TRBTempdatabase to convert the compressed blob data into different tables that are usable in the Reportbuilder runtime reportdesigner. 
TdmRBReport has access to TdmReportBaseData for all kinds of report-related data (type of report, report calculationsettings, etc). TRBTempDatabase is constructed in TdmRBReport but has to have access to TdmReportBasedata. So this is now done using the construction above:

```
constructor TRBTempDatabase.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);

  FdmReportBaseData := TdmRBReport(FindOwnerClass(Owner, TdmRBReport)).dmReportBaseData;
end;{- .Create }
```

My feeling is that this means that TRBTempDatabase knows a lot of its owner, and  I was wondering if this is some sort of code smell or Anti-pattern.

What are your thoughts about this? Is this a code smell? If so, what is a better way?

Comment: code smell? :)) 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: It could be. How easy is it for you to unit test the *current object*. If it's hard because of the dependencies on the owner, I would consider it something to be dealt with. You could replace the construct with Dependancy Injection.

Comment: @Lieven - We're not doing any unit tests (yes i know!!). Actually i've just started reading about it, and getting very enthousiastic about it. Guess this reading got me thinking about the construction above ...

Comment: The example in the question is a case of undesirable "Coupling" (dependencies) between classes.  I don't know if I would talk about every good and bad practice as having a "smell".  I think it's a lot more clear to talk about good OOD/OOP, and less-than-optimal OOD/OOP.  Keeping track of the SOLID principles in particular, might be a bit more formal and useful to the OP than talking about smells.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the description presented here I regard this as mildly smelly.  However, it seems easy to fix.

I'd be inclined to pass the `dmReportBaseData` object into the constructor of any component that needs it. This makes the contract clear at compile time rather than enforcing it at runtime as you currently do.

As it currently stands, the contract you enforce is stronger than it needs to be.  Although `TRBTempDatabase` only requires a `dmReportBaseData` instance, it will only function if it can get that instance from a `TdmRBReport` report object.

Making this change would also allow `TRBTempDatabase` and `TdmRBReport` to have a divorce and still function successfully.  And as @Lieven points out in the comments, this would likely make testing easier.

Comment: @Bascy You're welcome. Good question by the way!

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing in a base class is maintaining a reference to a parent object then no, it's not code-smell, it's a perfectly legitimate use.  You can explicitly design a base class to carry information about "something that might come later."

If the base class is relying on some characteristic of the derived class that isn't present in itself (i.e. the generalized class relies on a specialization of one of its children) then yeah, that might be a bit funky.

Comment: I noticed the example i gave wasn't quite accurate, fixed it. The case isn't that a base class knows something about a derived class. It is indeed knowing something about its Parent (Owner/Creator). You state that that is "perfectly legal" but like Lieven said it must make unit tests harder because of the implicit dependency, not?

Comment: @Bascy: That's why it is good to *make the dependency explicit* and ensure that the child only uses the public contract of the parent/factory. Whether or not the code is still smelly after that is out of the scope of the answer.

Comment: @Bascy - I think my answer is a bit off the mark now that you've updated the question but when I say "explicitly design" I mean specify a contract that can be enforced at compile-time. David's answer is great because it does that in a very lightweight and easily maintainable way. Implicit dependencies (i.e. assumptions) should make unit tests fail but don't always so it's better to rely on your compiler to find errors when you can.